# Retain filename while downloading a file with bottle static_file

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

What I'm trying to achieve is to download a file (zipped log folder) from path with static_file and retain the original file name. Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/logs')
def download_logs():
    filename = 'logs_' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    print(filename)
    shutil.make_archive(filename, 'zip', 'logs/')
    return static_file(filename + '.zip', './')
```

So as you see I want to zip log folder to archive named by date and time and download the file. Downloaded file should be downloaded with the same name as I zipped it on back-end. Currently file is downloaded as logs.zip so it gets the name of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `download` argument. This will force the browser to display the download dialog - in your case, that is happening automatically, because a browser can't open a zip file. But if you tried to "download" e.g. a HTML page this way, it would display directly instead of downloading.

More to the point, this allows you to specify filename that the browser should use to save the downloaded file. In your case, it should be sufficient to use `static_file(filename + ".zip". "./", download=True)`, which uses the original filename. Alternately, you can supply your own name with `download="my.name.goes.here"`. Have a look at 'Forced Download' in the [documentation](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#static-files).